# Getting the values from array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. In the model, I have the following code:

```
public function get_all_subjects()
{
   return $this->db->get('subjects');
}
```

In the controller, I have:

```
public function index()
{
   $this->load->model('subjects');
   $data['content'] = $this->subjects->get_all_subjects();

   $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

I am trying to get the values in the view:

```
foreach($content as $val)
{
   echo $val['subject']; //i am getting error, Message: Undefined index: subject
}
```

The fields in the `subjects` table are `subject_id` and `subject`.

I am getting this error message:

> Undefined index: subject

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public function get_all_subjects()
    {
        return $this->db->get('subjects')->result_array();
    }
```

You are not returning result from your query. You have just run the query.

Comment: `return $this->db->get('subjects')->result_array();` should do the trick and would avoid you from creating unnecessary variables: `$q`. Maybe @DeiForm wants to update his function.

Comment: Yes I heard of this chaining method. But for beginers the step by step method is easily to understand